# Transpose some columns based on condition in another two columns in sql

Tags: sql, sqlite, pivot

I am new in SQL and please forgive for that. I have a scenario where I should use SQL to get the result -

I have a table as given below.

```
User    System  Roles
 U1      S1      R1
 U1      S1      R2
 U1      S2      R1
 U2      S1      R1
 U3      S2      R1
 U3      S2      R2
 U3      S2      R3
```

I need to use SQL and get the result as given below.

```
User    System  Role1   Role2   Role3
 U1      S1      R1      R2 
 U1      S2      R1     
 U2      S1      R1     
 U3      S2      R1      R2       R3
```

The issue here is that the User Count, System Count and Role count is not constant - it can vary each time.

I tried to do it with my little SQL knowledge, but could not achieve this. If someone can help with this, that would be very helpful.

Thanks,
Hari

Comment: Can a R4 suddenly show up? What's the expected result if that happens?

Comment: try to look for "SQL PIVOT" on stackoverflow and/or google.  Do a try, then post the query you tried

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: @jarlh: Yes, R4 and similarly any number of roles can come up. If it is a new user and new system [Let us say User U4 and System S3], it should come as a new row, with R4 under the column Role 1. Hope you understood this. Ideally, I need to get a list of roles for unique users and systems.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Thanks for letting me know about the image part. Apologies, I was not aware of this. Regarding the tool I use, it is called LiveCompare which uses SQL to manipulate the data that we have.

Comment: @etsa : The tool which we use - LiveCompare - do not support some of the SQL commands [unfortunately :(]. But let me give a try on PIVOT and get back with the result. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: It is SQLite